# How to extract data from web to excel based on given input?

Tags: python, excel, web-scraping, vba

I want to extract tabular data based on given name and time period and save it to excel. 
This is the link [stock market info](https://www.nseindia.com/products/content/equities/equities/eq_security.htm) 
Here is a snapshot
[image] 
There is an option in the webpage "*Download file in csv format*", but I want to automate this process, because I need some 100 companies data.

I tried the web query option in excel, but the above mentioned link doesn't show any tabular symbol for me to import.

I just want some pseudo code to begin with. Also is it possible in the first place?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hope this helps.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

symbol = "Company name"
from_date = "19-12-2016"
to_date = "20-12-2016"
URL = "https://www.nseindia.com/products/dynaContent/common/productsSymbolMapping.jsp?symbol=%s&segmentLink=3&symbolCount=3&series=ALL&dateRange=+&fromDate=%s&toDate=%s&dataType=PRICEVOLUMEDELIVERABLE" % (symbol,from_date,to_date)

r = requests.get(URL,verify=false)
bso = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'html.parser')

outfile = symobl+'_'+from_date+'_'+to_date+'.csv'
data = ''

for tag in bso.find_all('th'):
    data += tag.text.split()+','
data = data[:-1]+'\n'

for row in bso.find_all('tr')[1:]:
    for field in row.find_all('td'):
        data += field.text.split()+','
    data = data[:-1]+'\n'

with open(outfile,'w') as f:
    f.write(data)
```

Comment: Thanks buddy. I never thought it would be that easy.